# getting linking error while compiling WEBRTC in QT(Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: c++, qt, webrtc

I'm getting the following error:

> testvideocapturer.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV17TestVideoCapturer[_ZTV17TestVideoCapturer]+0x78):
>   undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to
>   cricket::VideoCapturer::OnMessage(rtc::Message*)'

I'm using the tarball :
https://github.com/osblinnikov/webrtc-docker/tree/master/workspace
Can anyone help me regarding this issue.

My gcc version is 4.8
QT version is 5.0.2